# How can I add spaces in string before non sequential capital letters, while excluding sequential capital letters?

Tags: regex, angular, string, pipe

I made a pipe in angular where I get the name of an enum and I want to add spaces in the name before capital letters. However, some of the names consist of two sequential capital letters and these I don't want to split.

Expected result:

> LordOfWar -> Lord Of War
>
> HQ -> HQ

Actual result:

> LordOfWar -> Lord Of War
>
> HQ -> H Q

Regex: `/([A-Z])/g`

Pipe snippet: https://gist.github.com/FrisoDenijs/fc5d8a4abe2ce6a8e3544dd1f071a063

So far it's just "HQ", so I also tried to exclude HQ with a negative lookahead `/((?!HQ)|[A-Z])/g`, however this gave the following result:

> LordOfWar -> L o r d O f W a r
>
> HQ -> H Q

Optimally I would like a general regex so if I get another similar situation I don't have to add another exclusion.

Otherwise I would like to know how to exclude HQ (and how to add more exclusions to it for later)

Comment: Add `+` quantifier: `/([A-Z]+)/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two groups should do the trick: `replace(/([a-z]+)([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')`.